# The return type 'Transaction' isn't a 'Future<_>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future<void> init() async {
    if (!_initialized) {
      _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

      User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      _uid = user.uid;

      _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
        var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc("users/$_uid");
        db.runTransaction(
            (transaction) => transaction.update(ref, {constants.fcm: event}));
      });
```

I'm getting a return type error in this line:

```
db.runTransaction(
                (transaction) => transaction.update(ref, {constants.fcm: event}));
```

**The return type 'Transaction' isn't a 'Future<_>', as required by the closure's context**

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the method explicit, so Dart tries to return the result of the last line of code (`db.runTransaction`), which returns a `Transaction`.

Since the method is marked to return `Future<void>`, which is not the same as a `Transaction`, you get the error you posted.

Why did you mark the method as returning a `Future`? Does it really need to return anything? If so, what?